# How do I transpose a column to a matrix in Excel?

Tags: excel, matrix, transpose

I work in Excel on a MacBook and I don't know how to transpose ,for example, a column of 9 elements to a 3x3 matrix. I tried with TRANSPOSE function but the results are not correct because the first column of the matrix will be the first element repeated 3 times and so on.

Comment: You might want to read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in column **A**, pick some cell and enter:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,COLUMNS($A:A)+3*(ROWS($1:1)-1),0)
```

and then copy both across and down.

[image]