# Use IFERROR, INDEX, MATCH if the amount of column is limited

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to know if it would be possible to use the IFERROR, INDEX, MATCH function on below scenario.

D2:`=INDEX($A$2:$A$16, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$1:$D1, $A$2:$A$16), 0))`

E2: `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$16, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D2:D2,$B$2:$B$16)+IF($A$2:$A$16<>$D2, 1, 0), 0)), "")`

H2: `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$16, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D2:D2,$C$2:$C$16)+IF($A$2:$A$16<>$D2, 1, 0), 0)), "")`

I2: `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$16, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D2:H2,$C$2:$C$16)+IF($A$2:$A$16<>$D2, 1, 0), 0)), "")`

[image]

Based on the data of Countries and Cities filled in yellow on the left, by using the IFERROR, INDEX, MATCH formula I managed to get all the data I need. Now if there are more than 3 City, I want for the excel to continue the list of cities by creating another row under it as example of row filled in red.

I hope it makes sence. Let me know if it's possible.

Comment: So there are more than 3 cities. Perhaps get a list using unique().

Comment: That's a problematic data layout. Your yellow table already contains the unique values in a flat table. What reason is there for breaking it down into three cities per row?

Comment: i am planning to use the data for csv datamerging with indesign. the template can only fit 3 images. so if there are more than three images, i would need it to continue the rest of the image(s) on another template.

Comment: It’s not the complete solution to your case, but this is how to transpose a vector to a matrix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59212837/how-do-i-transpose-a-column-to-a-matrix-in-excel

Comment: thanks for the input, but I am newbie with the excel formulas, I don't know how the transpose could help with my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did tag `vba` as well as `excel-formula` so give this a try

```
Sub condense()
    Dim src, dest(), ws As Worksheet, srcRange As Range, i As Long, j As Long, countryCount As Long, rowNum As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set srcRange = ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 3)
    src = srcRange.Value2
    ReDim dest(1 To UBound(src, 1) - 1, 1 To 7)
    rowNum = 1
    i = 2
    Do While i <= UBound(src, 1)
        countryCount = Application.CountIf(srcRange.Columns(1), src(i, 1))
        For j = 1 To countryCount
            dest(rowNum + Int((j - 1) / 3), 1) = src(i + j - 1, 1)
            dest(rowNum + Int((j - 1) / 3), 2 + ((j - 1) Mod 3)) = src(i + j - 1, 2)
            dest(rowNum + Int((j - 1) / 3), 5 + ((j - 1) Mod 3)) = src(i + j - 1, 3)
        Next j
        i = i + countryCount
        rowNum = rowNum + 1 + Int((countryCount - 1) / 3)
    Loop
    ws.Cells(2, 4).Resize(rowNum, 7).Value2 = dest
    With ws.Cells(1, 4).Resize(1, 7)
        .Value2 = Strings.Split("Country,City1,City2,City3,Image1,Image2,Image3", ",")
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT 17-Jul-2022 (per comment from OP)**

```
Sub condenseInto4cols()
    Dim src, dest(), ws As Worksheet, srcRange As Range, i As Long, j As Long, countryCount As Long, rowNum As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set srcRange = ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 3)
    srcRange.Sort key1:=ws.Cells(2, 1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    src = srcRange.Value2
    ReDim dest(1 To UBound(src, 1) - 1, 1 To 9)
    rowNum = 1
    i = 2
    Do While i <= UBound(src, 1)
        countryCount = Application.CountIf(srcRange.Columns(1), src(i, 1))
        For j = 1 To countryCount
            dest(rowNum + Int((j - 1) / 4), 1) = src(i + j - 1, 1)
            dest(rowNum + Int((j - 1) / 4), 2 + ((j - 1) Mod 4)) = src(i + j - 1, 2)
            dest(rowNum + Int((j - 1) / 4), 6 + ((j - 1) Mod 4)) = src(i + j - 1, 3)
        Next j
        i = i + countryCount
        rowNum = rowNum + 1 + Int((countryCount - 1) / 4)
    Loop
    ws.Cells(2, 4).Resize(rowNum, 9).Value2 = dest
    With ws.Cells(1, 4).Resize(1, 9)
        .Value2 = Strings.Split("Country,City1,City2,City3,City4,Image1,Image2,Image3,Image4", ",")
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    srcRange.Sort key1:=ws.Cells(2, 2), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer and sorry for late reply. I manage to find a work around by giving a formula to create unique value within itself, for example the Country UK is repeated four times so the formula will create something like UK1, UK1, UK1 and UK2. This allow the excel to create another row based on the unique value. But I for sure will try to use the VBA that you posted since I am pursuing for cleaner look. Will let you know if it works.

Comment: I have tried your vba and it is exactly what I need. However is it possible to have it sorted based on the Cities? I found that the code will not work if there's same Country on separate row underneath. For example from the above table, there's another row containing UK (Edinburgh) right under Japan (Nagoya). I understand that it will not makes sense but the original data that I am working on is sorted based on the City column.

Comment: To sort by COUNTRY, add `srcRange.Sort key1:=ws.Cells(2, 1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes` immediately _after_ the `Set srcRange =` line (the code, as written, will not work if the data are sorted by city)

Comment: I added the line run the vba and then I sort it by City afterwards. It works perfectly! thank you so much!

Comment: Hello sir, could you help me improving the above code, if now I need additional column for City4 and Image4? @SpectralInstance

Comment: @gargilang, see new code appended to original answer

Comment: thank you so ever very much for your help. I can see you also update the code with the sorting as well that very kind of you, so I can remove my stupid sorting macro that I recorded. Now I understand a little bit how the code works and will not trouble you again if I need to add more column to it.

Comment: I also notice that when there's only one city for each country, an additional #N/A rows will be added on the bottom. And if there's only one row in the yellow list. The code will create two rows containing the same information. If this happen I usually just delete these rows. But for cleaner look, I would like to know if there's a way to fix them?

Comment: Try changing the 6th last line to ` ws.Cells(2, 4).Resize(rowNum - 1, 9).Value2 = dest`

Comment: I love you Sir! Wherever you are.